# Fourier transform of the product

Tags: fourier-transform

While reading the book “Modern Consensed Matter Theory”, I came across the following calculation.

$f(k) g(k) = \int d^d r e^{-i kr} f(-i \nabla) g(r)$

I know the convolution theorem for Fourier transform, but this formula still confuses me, can anybody explain how this calculation works?

Comment: It seems that convolution does not play an important role. It seems that it is the formal expression, so
$f(k)g(k)=\int_r e^{-ikr}\sum_nf^{(n)}(0)\frac{(-i\nabla)^n}{n!}g(r),$
then you act on $g(r)$ and find the result

Comment: Oh that is clever! So we could see it as transforming g only. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: integrate each and every gradient by parts,
$$
 \int d^d r ~ e^{-i kr} f(-i \nabla)\tilde g(r) = \int d^d r ~  \tilde g(r) f(i \nabla) e^{-i kr} = 
\int d^d r ~  f( k) \tilde g(r) e^{-i kr} = f(k)g(k).
$$

---

NB. To see why this is exactly equivalent to the convolution theorem, 
ignore fussy normalization distractions and work in  just one dimension. The important thing to remember is  [Lagrange's translation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator), $$e^{-y\partial_r} \tilde g(r)= \tilde g(r-y).$$ You then see that 
$$
f(-i\partial_r)~ \tilde g(r) = \int dy ~\tilde f(y)~ e^{-iy(-i\partial_r)}             ~   \tilde g(r)= \int dy ~ \tilde f(y) ~\tilde g(r-y),
$$
a convolution.